# How can I model a transitive relationship spanning multiple classes in Protégé?

Tags: protege

I would like to add a transitive property `islocatedIn` into my ontology. My goal is to infer that:

`City isLocatedIn Contient` using `City isLocatedIn Country`, `Country isLocatedIn Continent`.

I have seen examples of transitive properties with a single domain and range, however I have not successfully modelled a transitive property with a domain and range spanning multiple classes.
How can I represent this in Protégé to obtain the aforementioned inference?

[image: Class Hierarchy]
[image: isLocatedIn]

Answer (score 0):

`Asia`, `China` and other concrete examples of  `Contient` /  `Country` / `City` should be individuals, not classes.
You can add class `Place`, for example (subclass of the main `owl:Thing` class and put you other classes to be subclasses of it too).Then just make your property to have Range only class Place.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I would like to clarify - I understand that if the ontology were just as it appears, it would make more sense to have individuals for `Continent` / `Country` / `City`. Interpretation of individuals aside, is there another way to achieve this with the current class structure? Must all transitively related individuals share a common superclass?

Answer (score 0):

this is a late answer but it may be useful for other people.

In your case it could be a good solution to write a SWRL rule (https://protege.stanford.edu/conference/2009/slides/SWRL2009ProtegeConference.pdf) to declare that if `City isLocatedIn Country` and `Country isLocatedIn Continent`, then `City isLocatedIn Contient`.

This should look something like:

```
City(?city) ^ isLocatedIn(?city, ?country) ^ Country(?country) ^ isLocatedIn(?country, ?continent) ^ Continent(?continent) -> isLocatedIn(?city, ?continent)
```

you can do so in protégé editor normally.