# how to model a transitive relation through two properties?

Tags: owl, ontology, transitivity

My question is similar to the question
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979542/how-can-i-model-a-transitive-relationship-spanning-multiple-classes-in-protégé](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69979542/how-can-i-model-a-transitive-relationship-spanning-multiple-classes-in-prot%C3%A9g%C3%A9) ,

but I think different and interesting enough to warrant its own question.

The common example of a transitive property relation:
P(x,y) and P(y,z) => P(x,z)
Mom hasAncestor Grandma and Magda hasAncestor Mom => Magda hasAncestor Grandma

Our model has many relations like this:
P1(x,y) and P2(y,z) => P2(x,z)
Magda hasWorkRole Program Manager and Program Manager hasTask T0220  => Magda hasTask T0220

Is there already a known term for this type of relation? (seems pretty common)

Is there a way to model this in OWL?

Comment: did you try property chain axioms? That should be sufficient here. If not, SWRL is the next layer on top of OWL for more complex rules

Comment: Thanks! I have not used property chain axioms before. I feel like this is the answer from my quick research, but it may take a bit of time before I can model it. I'll share my results and upvote as soon as I can.

Comment: As simple as that. hasWorkRole o hasTask SubPropertyOf: hasTask